# How to check my server's upload and download speed?

Tags: php, performance, download, monitor

I bought a server and I need to check it's internet connection (speed).

Is there an easy way to do that?

I googled but I couldn't find anything...

I did this:

```
<?php

$link = 'http://speed.bezeqint.net/big.zip';
$start = time();
$size = filesize($link);
$file = file_get_contents($link);
$end = time();

$time = $end - $start;

$speed = $size / $time;

echo "Server's speed is: $speed MB/s";


?>
```

Is it correct?

Comment: For download speed this comes to my mind: Install a bittorrent command line client and download a linux distribution (not too new, but not too old, so that there are a lot of seeds). Usually all these seeds can send as fast as your server goes.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Does it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

$link = 'http://speed.bezeqint.net/big.zip';
$start = time();
$size = filesize($link);
$file = file_get_contents($link);
$end = time();

$time = $end - $start;

$size = $size / 1048576;

$speed = $size / $time;

echo "Server's speed is: $speed MB/s";


?>
```

Comment: i  did this:

<?php

$link = 'http://speed.bezeqint.net/big.zip';
$start = time();
$size = filesize($link);
$file = file_get_contents($link);
$end = time();

$time = $end - $start;

$speed = $size / $time;

echo "Server's speed is: $speed MB/s";


?>
Is it correct?

Comment: Nearly, it will output bytes per second, not MB/s

Answer (score 6):

If you have the remote desktop, then install a web browser and go to [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) and test a speed.

If not, here's how you can test your server's download speed:

- log in as root
- type `wget http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test`
- you'll see something like `100%[======================================>] 104,857,600 10.7M/s` - 10.7M/s is a download speed.

If you have more than 1 server, you can test upload speed by transfering files between 2 servers.

Comment: Or use `speedtest-cli`, which doesn't require running a GUI on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Have it connect to a server you know runs fast (such as Google). Then, measure how long it takes from sending the first packet to receiving the first packet - that's your upload time. The time from receiving the first to last packets is the download time. Then divide by the amount of data transferred and there's your result.

Example:

```
$times = Array(microtime(true));
$f = fsockopen("google.com",80);
$times[] = microtime(true);
$data = "POST / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
       ."Host: google.com\r\n"
       ."\r\n"
       .str_repeat("a",1000000); // send one megabyte of data
$sent = strlen($data);
fputs($f,$data);
$firstpacket = true;
$return = 0;
while(!feof($f)) {
    $return += strlen(fgets($f));
    if( $firstpacket) {
        $firstpacket = false;
        $times[] = microtime(true);
    }
}
$times[] = microtime(true);
fclose($f);
echo "RESULTS:\n"
    ."Connection: ".(($times[1]-$times[0])*1000)."ms\n"
    ."Upload: ".number_format($sent)." bytes in ".(($times[2]-$times[1]))."s (".($sent/($times[2]-$times[1])/1024)."kb/s)\n"
    ."Download: ".number_format($return)." bytes in ".(($times[3]-$times[2]))."s (".($return/($times[3]-$times[2])/1024)."kb/s)\n";
```

(You will get an error message from Google's servers, on account of the `Content-Length` header missing)

Run it a few times, get an average, but don't run it too much because I don't think Google would like it too much.

Comment: Thanks, but the results I'm getting doesn't really make sense... When I download a file from my server it's at 600kb/s and I have a 100MB/s internet connection... Using your code I got this: RESULTS: Connection: 75.366973877ms Upload: 1,000,037 bytes in 0.192752122879s (5066.60377186kb/s) Download: 1,081 bytes in 2.69412994385E-5s (39183.8584071kb/s)

Comment: When you download a file from your server, your network is the bottleneck. Servers usually have a much better internet connection, which is why the test connects to another server.

Comment: Yes, and I usually download at 12 MB/s (From torrent and stuff) but from my server, only at like 600 KB/s

Answer (score 0):

For the download, you can create a script that will calculate the average download speed:

```
$start = time(true);

$fileSize = '10240'; // if the file's size is 10MB

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    file_get_contents('the_url_of_a_pretty_big_file');
}

$end = time(true);

$speed = ($fileSize / ($end - $start)) / $i * 8;

echo $speed; // will return the speed in kbps
```

Comment: First line. mictotime. Also, 100 KB = 102400 B, not 100000.

Comment: IMHO microtime would be better, and more accurate.

Comment: I noticed the `microtime` thing few seconds after posting. Thanks for pointing it out. Regarding the file size it's in my opinion not important, wouldn't make much difference in the result.

Comment: If the file would be 100 KB, the time/microtime would make a difference though :P

Comment: 100KB was just an example, that's why I mentioned "the_url_of_a_pretty_big_file" in the `file_get_contents()`.